# SQL- Grouping all data for one specific ID

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I am sure there is an easy solution to this, but I can't wrap my head around it. So I have a table that contains several columns:

**ID, Summary, Users**

However for one ID there is multiple users and each user has a different summary. All of that is fine, however the ID keeps on getting repeated for every user. I just want to show the ID once and all the data for it.

Example:

```
ID | Summary | Users
5  | Hi      | me 
5  | Hello   | you
5  | Stack   | him
5  | Over    | someone
```

What I want it to do:

```
ID | Summary | Users
5  | Hi      | me 
   | Hello   | you
   | Stack   | him
   | Over    | someone
```

So ID 5 would be only displayed as one row rather then 4 different ones.
I was trying some case statements, but that doesn't help. The group by clause would require an aggregate function, which would result in a sum or a count and not the actual ID. I am kind of lost or I missed something. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2017 @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something which is probably best handled in your presentation layer, e.g. something like PHP or Java.  But, there might be a way to do this directly from SQL Server:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Summary) = 1
         THEN CONVERT(varchar(10), ID)
         ELSE '' END AS ID_value,
    Summary,
    Users
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    ID,
    Summary;
```

[image]

### Demo

In order to make this work, there needs to be some sort of ordering by which we can say that a certain record from a group of `ID` values is "first," and thereby should report the `ID` value, while the other do not.  I used `ROW_NUBMER` for this, and displayed the `ID` value for the first summary value alphabetically.  Another note, I needed to cast the `ID` to text in the `CASE` expression, so that we can use empty string for the non showing `ID` records.

Comment: You're a life saver! Thank you so much for the clear explanation.